# Position some list element beside absolute element

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to position something beside absolutely positioned element ie in same horizontal line.

There is an unordered list. Within this list are five items with display set as inline-block. The first item contains a checkbox with position absolute. It is displayed in first line and the other four items in a separate line. How can I display them all next to each other.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whes230q/1/) for it.

```
<div class ='wrap'>
<ul class='menu'>
   <li>
     <input type="checkbox" checked>
       <h2><div class='btn' id='lines'/></h2>
     <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
  </p>
  </li>
  <li><a href=''>H</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>H</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>H</a></li>
  <li><a href=''>H</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS is...

```
  ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  perspective: 900;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul.menu li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display:inline-block;
}

ul.menu li input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 80%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  margin:0;
}

ul.menu li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ p {
  margin-top: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
}

h2 {
  line-height: 34px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:50px;
}


/*FOR MENU BUTTON*/

.wrap{background-color:#f3f3f3; width:100%;}

.btn { 
    position: relative;         
    margin-top:2%; 
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px; 
    height: 36px; 
    width:36px;  
}
.btn:before { 
    border-bottom: 17px double black;
    border-top: 6px solid black;    
    content:"";
    height: 5px; 
    position: absolute; 
    right:3px;  
    top: 4px; 
    width:30px; 
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please review my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want it like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/2t5vx3cq/

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
ul.menu {
  list-style: none;
  perspective: 900;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul.menu li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.o1 {
  order: 1;
}
.o2 {
  order: 2;
  align-self: flex-start;
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
}
ul.menu li input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 80%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.menu li input[type=checkbox]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 40px;
  height: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul.menu li input[type=checkbox] ~ p {
   translate(0, 0);
}
ul.menu li input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ p {
  margin-top: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translate(0, 50%);
}
h2 {
  line-height: 34px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
}
/*FOR MENU BUTTON*/

.wrap {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  width: 100%;
}
.btn {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
}
.btn:before {
  border-bottom: 17px double black;
  border-top: 6px solid black;
  content: "";
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 30px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <ul class="menu o2">
    <li><a href=''>H</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=''>H</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=''>H</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href=''>H</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='menu o1'>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" checked>

      <h2><div class='btn' id='lines'></div></h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.
        Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div>

  <p>

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta.
    Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean
    quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet.
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes but how can I get rid of unnecessary space below the button when content inside p is not displayed. I would like to shrink it. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, I got it, but anchor tags inside class o2 not working. For example `<li><a href = "http://example.com">Ex</a></li>`wont work.

Comment: @swapna, sorry, what I thought was trivial became a nightmare! I spent hours trying to close that space between `btn` and the second `<p>` lol  Once I close the space, everything still functioned, but the first `<p>` would just overlap the second  `<p>`! I have opened a chat room, so if you would like to pursue this issue further go [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/97879/positioning-complex-group-of-elements-pure-css?tab=general) I think if we combine what we have so far, we can resolve this.